# Find the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{ \pi }{ 2 }-\tan^{-1}(n^2))\ln(n!)$, is this correct?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

$ \color{black}{\begin{align} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(n^2))\times \ln(n!))
&=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(n^2))\times\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(n!))\\~\\
&=\left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\dfrac{\pi}{2})-\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\arctan(n^2))\right)\times\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(n!))\\~\\
&=\left((\dfrac{\pi}{2})- (\arctan(\infty^2))\right)\times\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(n!))\\~\\
&=\left((\dfrac{\pi}{2})- (\dfrac{\pi}{2})\right)\times\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(n!))\\~\\
&=\left(0\right)\times\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(n!))\\~\\
&=0\end{align}}$?

is the above method correct ?

Comment: No. $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\ln(n!)}=\infty$ and the rest of it goes to $0$ so you can't pull it out.

Comment: Ok , how should i tackle it.

Comment: No. You simply cannot apply the algebraic rule of limits to $\infty$ in multiplication.

Answer (score 5):

It is best to use:
$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(n^2)=\arctan\frac{1}{n^2}\in\left(0,\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
together with:
$$ 0\leq \log n! \leq \log n^n \leq n \log n $$
in order to prove that the limit is zero by squeezing, since:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n \log n}{n^2} = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

As Jack D'Aurizio suggested, rewrite $$\Big(\frac{ \pi }{ 2 }-\tan^{-1}(n^2)\Big)\log(n!)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\, \log(n!)$$ Now, consider the development of each term $$\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{3 n^6}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{10}\right)$$ (Taylor series) and  $$\log(n!)=n\log(n)-n+\frac 12 \log(2\pi n)+\frac{1}{12n}+\cdots$$ (Stirling series). Multiply; as shown by Jack D'Aurizio, the leading term is the product of the two first terms, that is to say  $\frac{n \log n}{n^2}$.